# get XML content of uploaded File PHP

Tags: php, xml, html

1. I want to upload a XML file to my Server.

   2. Prase it/ get content of
   3. Print this result out.

Step 4: I want to write every row of the XML file into my Database.

this is how I tried it jet.

xml_import.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "lets test";
    $uploaddir = 'C:\wamp\www\PLT';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo '<pre>';
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Datei ist valide und wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Möglicherweise eine Dateiupload-Attacke!\n";
    }

    echo 'Weitere Debugging Informationen:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    print_r($xml);
}
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="xml_import.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

    Diese Datei hochladen: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

I dont know why, but this i got back from the php script:

> Datei ist valide und wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen. Weitere Debugging
>   Informationen:Array (
>       [userfile] => Array
>           (
>               [name] => XML format.xml
>               [type] => text/xml
>               [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpBE4B.tmp
>               [error] => 0
>               [size] => 89835
>           )
>
> )
>
> ( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity "file:///C:/wamp/tmp/phpBE4B.tmp" in
>   C:\wamp\www\PLT\xml_import.php on line 18

**UPDATE:**

```
<xml>
<competition Category="Senior" Country="DE" Description="Senior" Version="1.5"/>
<row GName="Safksdlha" GlobalPos="0" Id="W004637" Name="MUNDKLY"/>
<row GName="Laklödfa" GlobalPos="0" Id="W002054" Name="ASSHJKDNAITE"/>
<row CompetitionStatus="AC" Date="20140904"  Time="12:59" Total="1343" ID="W004637"/>
</xml>
```

I need to get all GName and Name out of it could someone show it to me?

Comment: how does the xml file look like?

Comment: use **$uploadfile** instead of simplexml_load_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); => simplexml_load_file($uploadfile);

Comment: @philipp see the update it is only a part and ich had to change the data in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Change you PHP code from:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "lets test";
    $uploaddir = 'C:\wamp\www\PLT';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo '<pre>';
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Datei ist valide und wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Möglicherweise eine Dateiupload-Attacke!\n";
    }

    echo 'Weitere Debugging Informationen:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    print_r($xml);
}
?>
```

To this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "lets test";
    $uploaddir = 'C:\wamp\www\PLT';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo '<pre>';
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Datei ist valide und wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen.\n";

        echo 'Weitere Debugging Informationen:';
        print_r($_FILES);
        print "</pre>";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($uploadfile);
        print_r($xml);          

    } else {
        echo "Möglicherweise eine Dateiupload-Attacke!\n";
    }


}
?>
```